# Dynamically adjust single-posttype.php query, based on current taxonomies

Tags: query

I have a single-teamphoto.php template loading data from a Team Photo - Custom Post Type, showing team photos with team member names below, one photo at a time, with a navigation list of available years below, for choosing the year of the team photo. Above this navigation would be a selection for toggling between Men's or Women's photos, within that same sport.

(This template will load after a search is performed for a player name.)

Each of the CPT posts contain a photo, team member names, and taxonomies for both gender and sport.

I'm storing those variables using:

```
<?php
$team_gender = strip_tags( get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'teamgender') );
$currentGender = $team_gender;
?>
<?php
$term_sport = strip_tags( get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'teamsport') );
$currentSport = $term_sport;
?>
```

The query I'm currently using for the navigation list of years at the bottom is:

```
<?php
$teamposts = get_posts('post_type=teamphoto&teamsport=' . $currentSport . '&teamgender=' . $currentGender . '&numberposts=-1&orderby=title&order=asc');
foreach($teamposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<li<?php if ( $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID ) { echo ' class="current"'; } else {} ?>>                               
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_field('team_year'); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Men's / Women's Toggle**: I need to introduce the two buttons - to toggle between **Men's** and **Women's** team photos being displayed - still within the current sport being viewed. *(Altering the initial page query).* which is currently the standard:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

---

I'm not sure how to best accomplish the toggle between Men's / Women's photos, while still remaining inside of the current sport? Would jQuery be a good option for loading an alternate query?

My tabs for choosing men's vs women's is currently void right now:

```
<div id="sort-tabs">
<a href="#"><div id="sort-mens-tab"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="sort-womens-tab"></div></a>
</div>
```

Any recommendations how to best accomplish this?

Thank you,
Jonathon